# Conditional assignment for lists

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I know conditional assignments. If the first element evaluates to `nil` the second element is taken.

```
irb(main):004:0> nil || 42
=> 42
```

Is there a similar concept for lists, such as the second path only gets evaluated if the first is **empty** not `nil`.

```
irb(main):004:0> [] || [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I don't think there is. Can you describe your problem one step away from this? maybe there is a better solution there.

Comment: If you only want to use conditionals, `a.any? && a || [1, 2, 3]` would work. Having said that, I'd use a ternary, like @sawa suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Literally having

```
[] || [1,2,3]
```

is useless, so I guess you have it as a certain variable, say `a`, which might happen to be `[]`. The best you can do is:

```
a.empty? ? [1, 2, 3] : a
```

If you are not satisfied with this, and insist along the way you tried, then you need to define additional methods.

```
class Array
  def tweeze; self unless empty? end
end

a.tweeze || [1, 2, 3]
```